# Python classes and __init__ method

Tags: python

I am learning python via dive into python. Got few questions and unable to understand, even through the documentation.

1) ***BaseClass***

2) ***InheritClass***

What exactly happens when we assign a *InheritClass* instance to a variable, when the *InheritClass* doesn't contain an `__init__` method and *BaseClass* does ?

- Is the *BaseClass* `__init__` method called automatically
- Also, tell me other things that happen under the hood.

Actually the fileInfo.py example is giving me serious headache, i am just unable to understand as to how the things are working. Following

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `BaseClass.__init__` will be called automatically. Same goes for any other methods defined in the parent class but not the child class. Observe:

```
>>> class Parent(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     print 'Parent.__init__'
...   def func(self, x):
...     print x
...
>>> class Child(Parent):
...   pass
...
>>> x = Child()
Parent.__init__
>>> x.func(1)
1
```

The child inherits its parent's methods. It can override them, but it doesn't have to.

Comment: You meant to say, every method in the `BaseClass` will be called, irrespective of calling them or not ??

Comment: No, `child.func` will call `func` in the parent class if it does not exist in the child class.

Comment: The point is that on creating `Child`, there is a implicit call to the `__init__` method of `Child`, which is inherited whenever it is not explicitly defined.

Comment: @Farmboy, @FogleBird : Thanks !! Can we use the value derived from `BaseClass.__init__` method in the `InheritClass.methods` ??

Comment: If you want to call `Parent.__init__` in the `Child.__init__` method, you need to pass the child instance `self` as follows: `class Child(Parent): def __init__(self): Parent.__init__(self) #other child stuff`

Comment: In general if you have a `child.func` method, but you want to call the `parent.func` method, with an instance `c` of `Child`, then you need to call `func` as an unbound method, explicitly passing in the instance: `Parent.func(c)`. Normally, when you call `func` as a bound method to an instance `c` as `c.func()` this is converted to `Child.func(c)`, where `c` is the instance `self` in the method definition. If this seems confusing, keep in mind that typically overriding an inherited method is indication that the child class will not want access to the parents method.

Comment: The `__init__` method is the most common exception to this, where you are likely to want the setup accomplished in the parents `__init__` along with some custom setup for the child.

Comment: It would improve the readability of this discussion to move the explanation into the actual answer.

Answer (score 4):

@FogleBird has already answered your question, but I wanted to add something and can't comment on his post:

You may also want to look at the [`super` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super). It's a way to call a parent's method from inside a child. It's helpful when you want to extend a method, for example:

```
class ParentClass(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.y = y
        super(ChildClass, self).__init__(x)
```

This can of course encompass methods that are a lot more complicated, *not* the `__init__` method or even a method by the same name!