# Python, init method in an imported file

Tags: python, import, module

I'm getting a little confused about importing methods from another file.

I'm writing a Python script that imports from [`python-automata`](http://code.google.com/p/python-automata/). I've downloaded the file and in my `../Python/` directory, I have `DFA.py` and `myfile.py` stored.

In `myfile.py` I have this written on top:

```
import DFA
```

As I'm following what's written in the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html), I assume that in `myfile.py` I can use any method defined in `DFA.py`. That file has a method called `__init__` which takes in 5 arguments and initializes a `DFA`. Then I write this in `myfile.py`:

```
DFA.__init__(states, alphabet, delta(states, alphabet), start, accepts)
```

Where states, alphabet, delta, start, and accepts are all basic lists/functions that I have initialized in myfile.py.

But then when I try to run myfile.py, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 21, in <module>
    DFA.__init__(states, alphabet, delta(states, alphabet), start, accepts)
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (5 given)
```

I'm not sure why it says it takes 2 arguments, when `DFA.py` defines it as taking in 5 arguments. In `DFA.py`, I see:

```
class DFA:
    def __init__(self, states, alphabet, delta, start, accepts):
    ...
```

It seems like a similar errors I encountered earlier (see [Python import issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756569/python-import-issue) and [Python classes and __init__ method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831685/python-classes-and-init-method)) but I don't think that I need to deal with inheritance here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from DFA import DFA

a = DFA(states, alphabet, delta(states, alphabet), start, accepts)
```

EDIT: methods named `__xx__` are not meant to be called directly.

Some reading: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Thanks! That worked well! and +1 for giving me the extra link to read.

Answer (score 4):

You're importing `DFA` as a module, but you want to import the *class* within it instead. Try:

```
from DFA import DFA
```

You can then implicitly call `__init__` by calling the constructor on your `DFA` class:

```
DFA(states, alphabet, delta(states, alphabet), start, accepts)     
# ^ this calls __init__ on DFA
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put in `DFA.__init__()`, you're calling the `__init__` method for the entire module (I don't even know what that is defined as). You should use `DFA.DFA.__init__()`, which refers to the `__init__` method of the `DFA` class within `DFA.py`, or use:

```
from DFA import *
DFA.__init__()
```